# Symfony pass submitted form to function

Tags: php, forms, rest, symfony, doctrine

I'm creating a website where I want to have it all in a single page and a single url `"/"`.
All the forms are embedded modals (mainly three):

- One to modify user profile
- one to modify profile picture
- one to create project
  and i may add more as i progress,

After Logging in I'm reirecting to a method that loads the dashboard along with the forms

Now I want to handle each form submi by an independent method In what looks like a Crud,
How can I do that?

Is there a way to pass form data to be handled inside each of the methods below?

Here's my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\User;
use App\Form\UpdateImageType;
use App\Form\CreateProjectType;
use App\Form\UpdateUserType;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
/**
 * Class DefaultController
 * @package App\Controller
 * @Route ("/", name="main.")
 */
class DefaultController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @return Response
     * @Route ("/", name="home")
     */
    public function index(): Response
    {
        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', [
        ]);
    }


    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @param UserInterface $user
     * @return Response
     * @Route ("/profile", name="profile")
     */
    public function profileview(Request $request): Response
    {
        $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY');
        $userId = $this->getUser()->getId();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $user = $em->getRepository(User::class)->find($userId);
        $userInfoform = $this->createForm(UpdateUserType::class, $user);
        $userImageform = $this->createForm(UpdateImageType::class, $user);
        $createProjectform = $this->createForm(CreateProjectType::class);
        $userId = $this->getUser();
        //dd($userId);
        return $this->render('default/profile.html.twig', [
            'updateUser' => $userInfoform->createView(),
            'updateImage' => $userImageform->createView(),
            'createProject' => $createProjectform->createView(),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route ("/", name="updateUser")
     * @param Request $request
     */
    public function updateUser(Request $request)
    {
        dd($request);
    }

    /**
     * @Route ("/", name="updateImage")
     */
    public function updateUserImage($request, $form)
    {

    }

    /**
     * @Route ("/", name="newProject")
     */
    public function createProject($request, $form)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are going to have identical paths (`"/"`) then you need to specify different request methods for each so that the router will know what to call. Then make sure to set the correct method on each of the forms.

- https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#matching-http-methods
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods

From that info, I would suggest the following methods:

```
@Route ("/", name="home", methods={"GET"})

@Route ("/", name="updateUser", methods={"PATCH"})

@Route ("/", name="updateImage", methods={"PUT"})

@Route ("/", name="newProject", methods={"POST"})
```

- https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#changing-the-action-and-http-method

That shows different ways to change the form method:

```
$userImageform = $this->createForm(UpdateImageType::class, $user, [
  'method' => 'PUT',
]);
```

### Note:

> If the form’s method is not `GET` or `POST`, but `PUT`, `PATCH` or
> `DELETE`, Symfony will insert a hidden field with the name `_method`
> that stores this method. The form will be submitted in a normal `POST`
> request, but Symfony’s routing is capable of detecting the _method
> parameter and will interpret it as a `PUT`, `PATCH` or `DELETE`
> request. The [`http_method_override`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#configuration-framework-http-method-override) option must be enabled for this to
> work.
>
> -- https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#changing-the-action-and-http-method